# Getting the number of records read by Rabbit mQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, rabbitmq-exchange, spring-rabbit

We are having application that read multiple files from remote.Now we have to maintian a log of the number of records read from each file by Queue Consumer.Can anyone please help ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: With spring integration I read muliple files and insert rows from these files into Rabbit MQ.Now I have to keep a count of number of rows read from each file after all the messages have been consumed.So in short, if file1 has 100 records and file2 has 50 records then I have to log that file1 had 100 reocrds and queue read 100 records of file1,file2 had 50 records and queue read 50 records from file2.In case, due to some reason if queue reads only 99 reocrds from file1 then I have to change the logger accordingly.Thanks in advance

Comment: So, why can't you just count the messages as you process them?

Comment: Are you concerned only that the consumer _reads_ the record from RabbitMQ, or also that it processes it successfully?  If this is about some kind of audit - that the same number of rows as posted to RabbitMQ, are processed - then you might want to count only at the point of successfully processing.  Have you considered possible multiple delivery from RabbitMQ and de-duplication?  (A consumer might process the record successfully, but the nack might not reach RabbitMQ server, and the message might be redelivered - leaving your count reading 101 for 100 originals - unless you handle deduping.)

Comment: (I meant *ack* might not reach RabbitMQ server, not nack, of course)

Comment: See the problem is that my application will be continuously looking for file.So say 1 file is under process ,I may get a new file.So issue is how do I make sure that the first file has completed processing and I can log the count details somewhere.Because I dont want multiple logs of the count.1 log per file which will state the number of records read from file and number of records processed by rabbit mq

Comment: Can you please update on this ? Thanks in advance @GaryRussell

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your issue. You can include the originating file name in a message header and keep a count of messages based on that.